# InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32] vs. [180]

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

**Problem:**

I am a beginner when it comes to deep learning implementation using python and I'm really stuck on this one particular issue.
I have an input data of shape [180,11,1]. I wanted to implement LSTM on this training data and I used the following code:

```
model.add(LSTM((1), batch_input_shape=(180,11,1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM((1), return_sequences=False))
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
             optimizer="adam",
             metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 10)
```

When I fitted the model, I got the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32] vs. [180]
     [[{{node training/Adam/gradients/loss/lstm_2_loss/sparse_categorical_crossentropy/weighted_loss/mul_grad/Mul_1}}]]
```

Not sure why I am getting this error. Any help is appreciated.